# identifying indices(java)

Tags: java, whitespace, indices

it makes me sick ..can you help me with this one? my problem is to identify the whitespaces on my java program and the indices of it but i dont know how to identify the indices(JAVA). heres my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class CountSpaces
{
public static void main (String[] args)
  {
   System.out.print ("Enter a sentence or phrase: ");
   Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
   String str=input.nextLine();
   int count = 0;
   int limit = str.length();
    for(int i = 0; i < limit; ++i)
    {
     if(Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(i)))
     {
      ++count;
     }
    }
```

thanks ahead.

Answer (score 4):

Use an `ArrayList` to record the indices. This also eliminates the need for a count as the number of entries in the list is the number of occurrences.

```
ArrayList<Integer> whitespaceLocations = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i = 0; i < limit; ++i)
{
    if(Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(i)))
    {
        whitespaceLocations.add(i);
    }
}

System.out.println("Whitespace count: " + whitespaceLocations.size());
System.out.print("Whitespace is located at indices: ");
for (Integer i : whitespaceLocations)
{
    System.out.print(i + " "); 
}

System.out.println();
```

Comment: Why you are using `i.toString()` in `System.out.print(i.toString() + " ");`? This will work `System.out.print(i + " ");`. **OR** Simple and mostly used [in my opinion] `System.out.print(i);`. Also *no need* of `System.out.println();` at the end.

Comment: While you're correct in that the former isn't needed ... it's going to happen anyway ::shrug::. The latter on the other hand, is for readability. Your version would print something akin to `Whitespace is located at indices: 251022` with no carriage return whereas the code above prints `Whitespace is located at indices: 2 5 10 22`.

Comment: Oh! yes. Didn't noticed that you are using `print` and not `println`. But still thinks you should remove toString(); it is unnecessary. ;-)

Comment: Pedantic point - I would favour LinkedList in this case as the list has to dynamically resize and there is no need for efficient random access.  I would also declare it as List<Integer> rather than explicitly specifying the list type.

Comment: Yeah .. I thought of that after posting, but decided to leave it ::shrug:: In this case I don't think it's a huge deal. I could argue that in a real word scenario you might want to know where the third space is.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(i)))
```

You already doing the most of it. If the above condition is true, then at **index i** you have the whitespace character. How ever, if you need to keep track of all the indices, then copy the index **i** to an array in the `if`.